# Ignore characters in preg_match_all output

Tags: php, regex, match

I have this regex:

```
preg_match_all('/{.*?}/', $html, $matches);
```

Which returns all strings that are written inside curly braces. The $matches variable contains the { and } characters also. How can I remove them?

I don't want to do:

```
if ($matches[0] == "{variable}")
```

And I don't want to add ( and ) characters to the regexp because I don't want to use:

```
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $html, $matches);
if ($matches[0][0] == "variable")
```

So is there a simpler way to remove the curly braces from the $matches within the regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PCRE (PHP's implementation of regex), you can use lookarounds to do zero-length assertions. A lookbehind, `(?<=...)`, will make sure that expression occurs behind the internal pointer. A lookahead, `(?=...)`, will make sure that expression occurs ahead of the internal pointer. These can both be negated if need be: `(?<!...)` or `(?!...)`.

---

This brings us to this expression:

```
(?<={).*?(?=})
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/xV9cE9/1)

---

Implement it the same way:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<={).*?(?=})/', $html, $matches);
// $matches[0] = 'variable';
```

---

@CasimirEtHippolyte makes a good point. This is a great example of where a lazy dot-match-all is not necessary and will potentially decrease performance with backtracking. You can replace the `.*?` with `[^}]*` to match 0+ non-`}` characters.

Comment: Note, you may want to use the `s` modifier. This will make your `.*?` match newline characters as well.

Comment: Beautiful! Just beautiful! Worked like a charm. I hope this doesn't have a huge impact on the performance of the regex. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @unska: If you want to improve performances, replace `.*?` with `[^}]+`

Comment: @unska it should have minimal, if any, performance impact compared to `{.*?}`. It will work the same way, but just *assert* for the `{` instead of actually matching it `{`. In other words, there is no "extra" logic for the lookarounds.

Comment: ... Or `[^{}]+` to avoid falsevar, at *"{falsevar{var1} {var2}}"*

Answer (score 3):

Or [reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) after the `{` and match characters, that are not `}`. If `{}` are balanced, don't need another `}`

```
{\K[^}]*
```

See [example on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lE2qB9/2)

Comment: can you provide a refrence to all these `\K`,*SPOT etc PCRE function where they are described in detail.In perl docs it is not very understandable

Comment: @vks I added a [link for \K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) the other you mean [Special Backtracking Control Verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.0/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) ?

Comment: got in in the reset link.This is again a better answer :)

Comment: Thanx a lot .will go through those to learn these as well. :)

Comment: @vks sure you know the [Regex FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) here on Stackoverflow already don't you? Always a good quick-reference I think.

Comment: :O never new something of that sort.That is just great.thanx a lot . happy regexing :)

Comment: Almost put this solution, as it is probably how I would do it. But I feel dirty preaching `\K` when you can use a lookaround, since one is more supported across flavors. Either way, +1 for the change in pace :)

Comment: @Sam As the question is about "ignore characters" and php tagged, I thought `\K` should at least be mentioned. Yours is a greatly explained and more compatible solution as you said. Already upvoted of course :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<={).*?(?=})
```

Replace your regex by this.This will work.